# Azure DevOps git -- best next action to mitigate when `1 commit behind and 1 commit ahead`

Tags: git, azure-devops

In an Azure DevOps git repo, I have a dev and master branch.  Currently dev is 1 commit behind and 1 commit ahead of master.  I created a pull request from master to dev so dev is no longer behind master. After the pull request is committed, dev is 2 commits behind master and 1 ahead.  I was expecting dev to be 0 commits behind master and 1 ahead after the pull request.  What am I missing?

Comment: Not get your response for several days,  is there any update for this issue? If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for [marking it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which will also help others in the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your [merge type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#limit-merge-types) of your pull request.

- Basic merge (no fast-forward) - creates a merge commit in the target
  whose parents are the target and source branches.
- Squash merge - creates a linear history with a single commit in the
  target branch with the changes from the source branch. Learn more
  about squash merging and how it affects your branch history.
- Rebase and fast-forward - creates a linear history by replaying
  source commits onto the target branch with no merge commit.
- Rebase with merge commit - replays the source commits onto the target
  and still creates a merge commit.

> I was expecting dev to be 0 commits behind master and 1 ahead after
> the pull request

You can try to use **Rebase with merge commit** merge type when you complete your pull request.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  We were using squash merge and didn't fully understand that that commit history would not sync to the target branch.